# ogr2ogr{gdalUtils} correct syntax to set Ground Control Points for vector georeferencing

Tags: shapefile, gdal, r, ogr2ogr, gdalutils

I would like to know correct syntax of **R {gdalUtils}** package (version 2.0.1.7) to georeference Shapefiles using corner points as GCPs. (These Shapefiles have y=height and x=width information, without datum / projection.)

On *OSGeo4W shell*, **ogr2ogr** works fine and it returns georeferenced Shapefile.

> ogr2ogr -gcp 0 0 40 40 -gcp 0.263693 0 145 40 -gcp 0.263693 -0.237619 145 -50 -gcp 0 -0.237619 40 -50 -f "ESRI shapefile" Myreferenced.shp My.shp

Trying to do the same by **gdalUtils::ogr2ogr()**,

```
library(gralUtils)
src_datasource_name # input Shapefile
dst_datasource_name # output Shapefile (georeferenced)

# ogrinfo() works fine
ogrinfo(datasource_name = src_datasource_name, al = TRUE, so = TRUE)

# ogr2ogr() fails
ogr2ogr(src_datasource_name= src_datasource_name,
        dst_datasource_name= dst_datasource_name,
        f= "ESRI Shapefile",
        gcp = list(1:4,
                   c(0, 0, 40, 40),
                   c(0.263693, 0, 145, 40),
                   c(0.263693, -0.237619, 145, -50),
                   c( 0, -0.237619, 40, -50)
                  )
       )
```

What I am struggling in the **ogr2ogr()** syntax is how to provide multiple GCP points.
As you see above, I tried to give GCPs as a list, which did not work.

Does anybody know how to set GCPs with 4 corner points in **gdalUtils**? Unfortunately use cases of **gdalUtils** are relatively scarce on internet.

---

About my Shapefile Data

- They were originally hand-drawn by MS-Powerpoint and saved as .eps file. It has bounding box with known LatLong corner points (UL, UR, LR, and LL). The .eps file was then converted to .shp file.
- Conversion from .eps to .shp changes everything into Line feature (Multilines Shapefile).
- This Shapefile does not have projection information but its dimension can be read by **ogrinfo**. It is (0, 0) at the UL corner, with height (eg y= -0. 238) and width (x= 0.263). Measured unit is meter. These y and x values can vary among drawings.

Error message from above **ogr2ogr()** is

```
[1] "ERROR 1: Failed to compute GCP transform: Not enough points available"
```

However increasing points does not seem a solution, as **ogr2ogr** on *OSGeo4W shell* works fine on the same data and GCP sets. This error is due to my wrong code, but I do not know how to fix it.

---

[EDIT] by QGIS Raster georeferencer, .points would look like this image.

[image: gcpimage]

```
mapX,mapY,pixelX,pixelY,enable
40,40,0,0,1
145,40,0.26300000000000001,0,1
40,-50,0,-0.23799999999999999,1
145,-50,0.26300000000000001,-0.23799999999999999,1
```

---

[EDIT2] Another way of applying GCPs:

```
ogr2ogr(src_datasource_name= src_datasource_name,
        dst_datasource_name= dst_datasource_name,
        f= "ESRI Shapefile",
        gcp = c(0,                0,  40,  40),
        gcp = c(0.263693,         0, 140,  40),
        gcp = c(0.263693, -0.237619, 140, -50),
        gcp = c(0,        -0.237619,  40, -50)
        )
```

This way R returned following error

> Error in ogr2ogr(src_datasource_name = src_datasource_name, dst_datasource_name = dst_datasource_name,  :
>     formal argument "gcp" matched by multiple actual arguments

I don't know what it means...

---

[EDIT3]
Suggested approach to put variables into `-optfile`.

```
ogr2ogr(src_datasource_name= src_datasource_name,
        dst_datasource_name= dst_datasource_name,
        f= "ESRI Shapefile",
        optfile = "C:/temp/my_gcp.txt"
        )
```

Below is my tested formats (my_gcp.txt) yet successful...

```
# trial 1
"-gcp 0 0 40 40 -gcp 0.263693 0 145 40 -gcp 0.263693 -0.237619 145 -50 -gcp 0 -0.237619 40 -50"
# trial 2
"gcp = c(0, 0, 40, 40,), gcp = c(0.263693, 0, 145, 40), gcp = c(0.263693, -0.237619, 145, -50), gcp = c(0, -0.237619, 40, -50)"
```

Error message was:

```
Error in ogr2ogr(src_datasource_name = src_datasource_name, dst_datasource_name = dst_datasource_name,  :
unused argument (optfile = "C:/temp/my_gcp.txt")
```

Comment: Print out the "gcp" once you have set the value with your list. How does it look like?

Comment: @user30184, Thank you for your response. I was not so sure what would be the best to print out to see its look, so I used QGIS to try to make somewhat similar. Maybe I am mistaken?

Comment: Make your code to print the contents of the variable. It may be -gcp followed by many mapX,mapY,pixelX,pixelY, while you will need many times "-gcp mapX,mapY,pixelX,pixelY".

Comment: Got that, but the suggested way, putting **-gcp** (or **gcp** without hyphen) commands in row (which is, genuine GDAL style) was what I had tried first. It seemed enumeration of objects was not acceptable to R.

Comment: @user30184 Apologies. Forgot to add the error message I got with multiple gcp lines. Just added as [EDIT 2] above. Hope this clarifies the situation better...

Comment: I'm wondering if it is not a bug. The documentation says "gps Numeric. c(ungeoref_x,ungeoref_y,georef_x georef_y,elevation)" So your proposition with`list` is wrong but `gcp = c(c(0, 0, 40, 40), c(0.263693, 0, 145, 40), c(0.263693, -0.237619, 145, -50), c(0, -0.237619, 40, -50))` doesn't work. I cam closer of the wished printed output with `gcp =  c('0, 0, 40, 40','0.263693, 0, 145, 40', '0.263693, -0.237619, 145, -50', '0, -0.237619, 40, -50')` but because it is not numeric, it breaks too.

Comment: I don't know how to write correct R either but as a workaround you could try to write gcp arguments into a text file and point ogr2ogr to read that with -optfile.

Comment: @nebi Many thanks for testing the code, and for your comment about approach of setting numeric / character values. I do agree *list* is a wrong way to go. I was also interested in your stratified concatenation `c(c(...))`, which sadly, did not work out for me. Hopefully it is not a bug......

Comment: @user30184 By `-optfile` flag, I just found your excellent answer to this post [ogr2ogr sql query from text file](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185072/ogr2ogr-sql-query-from-text-file/185141#185141). This switch seems to work for all **ogr** commands. In **gdalUtils** documentation there is an entry of `optfile` (in **ogrinfo**) so it seems promising. Added my trial (2 patterns so far) to [EDIT3]. I will keep trying to go this path. Thanks again!

Comment: @user30184 I made some trials, from time to time, by changing the style of -optfile. Now I think I will wait for updates on official documentation of gdalUtils package. Fingers crossed...